# Get amount of graphics memory

Tags: c++, windows, directx, direct3d11, dxgi

I know about [DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173058(v=vs.85).aspx), but in 32-bit builds Direct3D’s SIZE_T type is 4 bytes long, so I’m getting 3GB instead of 11.

Is there a way to get the correct value even in a 32 bit build?

P.S. I need the value to [calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) upper size for a large 2D texture array. While it’s not likely for a user to have 32-bit Windows with 11GB VRAM GPU, it’s quite possible to have 4GB VRAM with a 32-bit OS, e.g. as a result of upgrade. And I don’t want to limit my array to 0 in this case.

Comment: Using [`AdapterRam` from WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx) might be what you're after

Comment: @Tas it's uint32, i.e. won't work even in a 64-bit build.

Comment: Really the only way to figure out the maximum size is to try to create it...

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, there is no easy way to achieve this.

Instead, there are (Microsoft-style) multiple completely different ways to achieve this, each of it more complicated than the other.

There used to be the handy `pd3dDevice->GetAvailableTextureMem()` in DX9, but that's gone in DX11.

**[In this MSDN code example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DirectX-Video-Memory-ee7d8319)** you can find multiple ways to query the available video RAM (with source). I hope one of it fits for you.

Comment: I’ve already implemented the DXGI way. It fails in 32-bit builds when you have >= 4GB VRAM, because it returns byte size value in a 32-bit structure field.

Comment: But thanks anyway, the sample you’ve linked implements 4 other methods, will check these later.

Comment: A 32-bit application cannot access all 4 GB+ of VRAM which is why for 32-bit apps it returns a lower value. You need a 64-bit native app to see it all. See [this article](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3602/sponsored_feature_ram_vram_and_.php)

Comment: BTW the most recent version of that sample is on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/VideoMemory). The code is basically the same as the MSDN Code Gallery version, but it's been updated for newer versions of Visual C++.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: VRAM isn't ordinarily mapped into virtual address spaces, let alone all of it.

Comment: Actually it is, although in modern WDDM they utilize windowing to try to keep the overall VA space utilization down. See [Why Your Windows Game Won't Run In 2,147,352,576 Bytes](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/04/Why-Your-Windows-Game-Wont-Run-In-2147352576-Bytes.zip) from Gamefest 2007. You can try to use LargeAddressAware in 32-bit apps while running on an x64 OS, but if you want to use large amounts of VRAM, you need to use x64 native code.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn A 32-bit application can access all 4 GB+ of VRAM. You don’t need a 64-bit native app to see it all. See this article: https://github.com/Const-me/VRamLimits

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions that the created textures all have committed VRAM. Try actually uploading 14 GB of texture data. Then try rendering with it.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn See the update in that repo. Apart from execution time, the result’s the same. I was too lazy to render, instead I’ve implemented a simple method to read the texture data back from GPU.

Comment: @Soonts You execution time change is surely your app  starting to page like crazy. You should use the initial data at CreateTexture and log time of each creation to catch the start of paging

Comment: @galop1n I don’t want to measure VRAM in my app this way, it’s very inaccurate. I don’t know how much Windows and other apps have consumed. Also system RAM may be faster than VRAM, e.g. with window remote desktop, system RAM is local=on the server, but VRAM is remote=on the client PC. The formula in the documentation for max. resource size depends on “amount of dedicated VRAM”. Shouldn’t it be possible to query that amount without inaccurate measurements?

Comment: @Soonts Your test is flawed because you have no idea what the driver and d3d does behind the scene. The GPU memory is mapped to the same process virtual address space for all i know, so at any time, a 32bit process won't see more than 4GB without paging of your GPU, in fact no more than 2GB (mapped in the OS reserved virtual space ). That is the reality.

Comment: @galop1n In my test I’m writing then reading 16GB of textures, from a 32-bit process. I even verify that the data I read is correct. How exactly is that flawed? BTW, the process never consumes more than 800MB RAM.

Comment: @soonts The process goes on disk, this is what paging is for, you can try to disable the page file in the advanced setting, it won't be the same result.

Comment: @galop1n The process consumes just 800MB RAM, out of 16 GB. It doesn’t go anywhere. Windows kernel may or may not swap the data to HDD, but I’m 90% sure it doesn’t. You see, these textures are eventually needed on the GPU, to render stuff. The GPU has full access to system RAM, but not to HDD.

Comment: @galop1n Also, there’s “Dedicated GPU memory usage” graph in windows task manager. It shows me that my 32-bit app consumed all 11GB of VRAM.